# Accessing Akavache DatabasePath Value

Tags: sqlite, debugging, xamarin.forms, akavache

In my project I am trying to use the DatabasePath value that is in my Akavache object.  The odd thing is that I can only seem to see and access the DatabasePath property value during Debug mode only.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.  When the project is not running, I don't seem to have any way of seeing nor accessing the DatabasePath property in my Akavache object so that I can assign the value to a variable in my code.  Can someone please help me out with this mystery?  I hope the image I have attached makes sense.

[Akavache DatabasePath Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ0oR.png)

Regards,
Kai

Comment: at a glance, it doesn't appear that Akavache exposes the internal details of the SQLite connection publicly.

Comment: Hi Jason, Thanks for the reply.  I thought as much.  Just hope I can "Macgyver" some kind of solution to get that path.